# Why is the merge printing in reverse order

Tags: sorting, mergesort, divide-and-conquer

So, I was learning the Merge Sort Algorithm. and I was amazed to see that the merging is printed in reverse order. You can see I am printing the merge vector `v` at each step but I don't understand why is it in reverse order. The final answer if perfectly fine.

```
void merge(vector<int> &left, vector<int> &right, vector<int> &v) {
    cout << "merged vector is : \n";
    for (auto x : v)
        cout << x << " ";
    cout << endl; 

    int l = left.size();
    int r = right.size();

    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (i < l && j < r) {
        if (left[i] <= right[j]) {
            v[k] = left[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            v[k] = right[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (i < l) {
        v[k++] = left[i++];
    }
    while (j < r) {
        v[k++] = right[j++];
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Why are you displaying v before the merge instead of after the merge? The issue is probably due to a top down recursive merge sort, which will be sorting depth first, left first, but without seeing the merge sort code, I can't be sure.

Comment: @rcgldr Yes you are right. I actually displayed them after merge and guess what it worked !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You print the destination vector `v` at the **beginning** of each step. The contents and order of the destination vector depends on how you use implement the merge sort algorithm, namely how you split the original vector, how you invoke the `merge` function and what is the original contents of the source vector. If you want to track the behavior of the merge sort algorithm, you should print the vector after the merge operation.

Note also that:

- the index variables `i`, `j`, `k`, `l` and `r` should have type `size_t`.
- the `return;` statement at the end of the function is useless.